# Data Analysis of No-Opinion Options

Tags: missing-data, confirmatory-factor

In my questionnaire, I had a "no-opinion" option for several items on a 5-point-likert scale. I know, there is a lot of discussion about sense and non sense of those, but the fact is, i've got a data set with a lot of these values.

So the big question: How to analyse them!? Obviously it's important to display them in the descriptives and try to explain the high values in the different variables, but once i start to do the statistical procedures they are really annoying. I want to do a confirmatory factor analysis and some Structural equation modelling afterwards.

Can anyone help?
Thank you so much!!!
(My profs at university are not really helpful;) )

Answer (score 0):

In one of my notes:

Valid applications of the Wilcoxon Signed Ranks test.
1. the test is appropriate for small sample sizes.
2. the experiment measures a dichotomous independent variable.
3. the dependent variable are measured on 7-point Likert scale, which is an interval scale, and appropriate for the Wilcoxon Signed Ranks test.

Conduct Wilcoxon Signed Ranks tests to evaluate the data, one test for each question.